# How to stop one worker from delayed_job pool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, monit

Let's say I start a delayed job worker pool with `script/delayed_job --pool=high_priority,default --pool=* start` command and monitor it with monit:

```
check process delayed_job.0 with pidfile /var/www/project/shared/tmp/pids/delayed_job.0.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/project/current/script/delayed_job --pool=high_priority,default --pool=* start"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/project/current/script/delayed_job --pool=high_priority,default --pool=* stop

check process delayed_job.1 with pidfile /var/www/project/shared/tmp/pids/delayed_job.1.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/project/current/script/delayed_job --pool=high_priority,default --pool=* start"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/project/current/script/delayed_job --pool=high_priority,default --pool=* stop
```

This [appears to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071970/monitoring-multiple-delayed-job-workers-with-monit) be [a safe](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paneq/fe0c27d99c943ecb81023badf80b10d7/raw/4c01bab4105e3dc69b747c2ae20e9f8275606d90/log.txt) configuration regarding starting workers which crashed.

But let's say someone invokes `monit stop delayed_job.0` and it will also result in stopping `delayed_job.1`. How can I safely stop only one of those processes and keep the other running?

Comment: `-i 0` does not seem to work and results in stopping both processes.